# searching for a string in multiple servers out put in file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Hi folks I am trying to do a search multiple servers (for now 3 but it may go up).

the output the result in the file along with the server i found the string.

I am doing this:

```
for host in $(cat servers);
do
ssh -q -l user  $host "grep -oP '<url>.*:\K[^<]+' /opt/application/domain/config/jdbc/assetmanagement-xa-ds-jdbc.xml" >> test;
done;
```

I get the file test
with a list of the string (it is a DB SID).

```
cat test
DB_SID1
DB_SID2
DB_SID3
```

my server file has the list of the server ip's

```
cat servers
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.2.3
```

I would like to have like 2 columns in the test file a header and the server ip/name and DB SID name: (Like this)

```
Server        DB_SID_Name
192.168.2.1   DB_SID1
192.168.2.2   DB_SID2
192.168.2.3   DB_SID3
```

regards

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ paste servers test
192.168.2.1     DB_SID1
192.168.2.2     DB_SID2
192.168.2.3     DB_SID3
```

The `paste` utility creates columns of one or several files.  These are by default tab-delimited, but the delimiter could be changed to any single character using `-d`:

```
$ paste -d ':' servers test
192.168.2.1:DB_SID1
192.168.2.2:DB_SID2
192.168.2.3:DB_SID3
```

Adding column headers and redirecting to a file:

```
$ { printf '%s\t%s\n' 'Server' 'DB_SID_Name'; paste servers test; } >somefile
$ cat somefile
Server  DB_SID_Name
192.168.2.1     DB_SID1
192.168.2.2     DB_SID2
192.168.2.3     DB_SID3
```

Your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

{
    printf '%s\t%s\n' 'Server' 'DB_SID_Name'
    
    while IFS= read host; do
        ssh -n -q "user@$host" 'cat /opt/application/domain/config/jdbc/assetmanagement-xa-ds-jdbc.xml'
    done <servers |
    grep -oP '<url>.*:\K[^<]+' |
    paste servers -
} >somefile
```

This never creates the `test` file but pipes the output of your loop to `paste` directly.  It also correctly reads line by line from `servers` instead of expanding that whole file as a list for your `for` loop.

It also doesn't try to do anything more complicated on the remote host than to `cat` the relevant file.  The `grep` is moved to the local host (and is only executed once).

Comment: sorry you anwer was spot on. How do I accept your answer. I am new and a bit confused. Apologies

Comment: @NickG. No worries!  You ought to see a greyed-out checkmark to the left of the answer. Click that. It will turn it green.